# Binding an IEnumerable to a single column

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm binding my array of a abstract type with no problems to the datagrid. However, I just learned that a new property will be added and it's of type *IEnumerable*. I'm going to assume that the public properties of it are of type *String*.

How can I databind that new property so it displays anything useful in the datagrid? Testing a fake addition gives me only empty fields in that column. I can't split the new property into several columns because the count may vary.

Is it possible to achieve without explicit binding method at all?

I've got some hits when I searched but none of them gives me a clear answer. Possibly I'm just missing it due to confusion.

Comment: So what do you *want* to display? Assuming you get multiple strings (`IEnumerable<string>`), what do you want a cell to look like?

Comment: To begin with, as I'm only laborating at the moment, **anything** that refers to each element - be that the pointer, whole property value or *ToString()* method. Eventually, I'll need to control it in more details, so let's say I want to display a concatenated contents of all the object's property named *Donkey*. So the main question is if it's possible **automagically**. And I suspect that it is not.

Comment: Without any indication what you *did* it's extremely hard to help you without being **too broad**. You can write books about this. Have a look into [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) that should allow you to do anything you like. For example have a listbox in your cell listing all values in your property.

Comment: I fear you're right and that I'm asking the wrooong question due to ignorance. If we go about it a different way? I do *dataGrid.ItemsSource = GetFakedOrders();* and I wish to control the actual rendition of what's on in the table. Is that possible? I haven't found any events for that on the datagrid when intellisensing...

Comment: You do use XAML and MVVM, right? Post your XAML of the datagrid.

Comment: Hehe, you might have found the problem. In the XAML I only **create** the datagrid. I have nothing about databinding in there. It's only one line. *<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,117,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />*. Should I define the columns of the grid in XAML too? I still wish to control what the contents look like (if the autorenderred value is, say, "beep", I'd like it to be **by me explicitly** to be rendered as "BEEP", for instance).

Comment: Actually, based on [this article](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#manualColumns), I'm starting to think that my question is rather "*can I autogenerate all columns but one, which needs to be customized using a column/cell template*"...

Comment: Yes, you should define your columns in XAML, where you can have converters and if converters are not enough, even templates.

Comment: OK, then. I'll add *ItemSource* attribute to the XAML code. Just a (possibly very stupid) question - how do I point to the method that yields all the objects to be rendered? (Also, please put the compiled version of your comments as a reply so I can accept it as an answer.)

Comment: You cannot point to a method, you have to have a viewmodel that has a property which holds the results of your method.

Comment: Hehe, so I **was not** using MVVM... I'm assuming datagrid **must** have that and **can't** use a method yielding data...

Comment: If you are comming from a different background, Windows Forms for example, you may want to read a good book on WPF/XAML and the MVVM pattern first, because WPF was written to use that pattern. If you do use it, WPF is great and easy. If you don't, it's hard and unrewarding.

Comment: I've actually worked with MVC, so I get the **patter**. I just assumed that since I only have a single array to display (it's a very small application), the models and stuff could be automagically bound. The fact that I have no menu for adding a modelview to the solution (as I had with controllers, vies and models in MVC) in VisualStudio misled me as well... Perhaps I need a new solutions? I picked up the one that's WPF and assumed that it was enough...

Comment: No, you can just add a class, call it ViewModel and have a perfectly working view model. There is no special solution or project template for MVVM.

Comment: Oh, great, so I wasn't totally off. (Just a bit, hehe.) I'm assuming that the class needs to be attributed or deriving in a certain way. So I'll need to google that. It can't be as easy as just refering to the class's name, right?   :)

Comment: Actually, it's that easy. You need to set your Windows `DataContext` to your instance of the view model and that's it. If you need automatic change handling, you will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the view model class.

Comment: I think I got it working now. I still don't get to see anything in the data grid (unless I tell my model to explicitly return "*donkey*" form the property). But that's an issue of the view model not fetching the data anywhere so I've asked about it [in a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731270/data-not-displayed-in-the-gridview). Still - please put in a reply so I can greencheck it.